# Accessing a file object outside a try/catch block that creates it (Java)

Tags: java

I want to create a RandomAccessFile object (in Java) and both write to it and read to it. My problem is that, as far I know I seem to need to create the file within a try/catch block. If I try to create it outside a try/catch block and then initialize it within the block like this,

```
RandomAccessFile valueFile; 

try
{
    valueFile = new RandomAccessFile("valuefile.txt", "rw");
    for (int i=0; i<numOfNums; i++)
        valueFile.writeDouble(randomizer.nextDouble()*200);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the values file.");
    System.exit(0);
}

for (int i=0; i<numOfNums; i++)
{
    double total = 0;
    valueFile.seek(0); // go to beginning of file to start reading it.
}
```

then I get the error "unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". (I also get "variable valueFile might not have been initialized".)

But when I *do* create it within try/catch, like this,

```
try
{
    RandomAccessFile valueFile = new RandomAccessFile("valuefile.txt", "rw");
    for (int i=0; i<numOfNums; i++)
        valueFile.writeDouble(randomizer.nextDouble()*200);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the values file.");
    System.exit(0);
}

for (int i=0; i<numOfNums; i++)
{
    double total = 0;
    valueFile.seek(0);
}
```

I get "cannot find symbol: variable valueFile" on the later part of the program. I presume that that's because valueFile is considered local to the try/catch block? But then how do I create valueFile so it's *not* local to the try/catch block?

Comment: Use the first version, only set valueFile to `null` when it's declared.  Then either add a `throws IOException` clause to the method header or put a `try` range around your `seek` calls.  ('m assuming that the `seek` stands in for some more complex I/O code -- it's meaningless by itself.)

Answer (score 6):

I think your first approach was correct. The error isn't being caused by the file creation, but rather by the `valueFile.seek(0);` call. This can also throw an IO Exception, so you need it in a try/catch block as well.

***Edit:*** As Jon pointed out, your code still won't compile since `valueFile` might be uninitialized. Just initialize it to `null` and it will work.

```
RandomAccessFile valueFile = null;
```

You could instead use one of the methods described in Jon's answer to convince the compiler that `valueFile` is actually initialized by the time it gets to `valueFile.seek(0)`. His method is safer, but just initializing to `null` is a nice quick fix so that you don't have to clutter your code with unreachable `throw` statements.

However, I think it would be even better if you just move the declaration, initialization with the new `RandomAccessFile` and all accesses to the file within the same `try` block. I can't think of any good reason to split them up.

Comment: The first approach still wouldn't compile - see my answer for details.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I was assuming he'd move all references to `valueFile` into the same `try` block. If he doesn't then you're right, the compiler will complain about the variable being uninitialized (assuming it's not a field).

Answer (score 5):

The first version is *nearly* right - but there are two problems:

1. Your method doesn't declare that it can throw `IOException`, but your use of `valueFile.seek` could throw an exception. Either you need to change the method declaration, or catch and handle the exception.
2. The compiler doesn't know that `System.exit(0)` will never return normally - it thinks it's a normal method. So you have to change your catch block to end with something like:

   ```
   return;
   ```

   or

   ```
   throw new AssertionError("We'll never get here.");
   ```

   At that point, the compiler knows that if it gets beyond the try/catch block, `valueFile` *is* definitely assigned.

Note that if you move *everything* inside the `catch` block, both problems will go away - but I'd suggest that you'd be better off *not* catching anything at all, and instead just declaring that the method may throw `IOException`:

```
public void foo(int iterations) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile valueFile = new RandomAccessFile("valuefile.txt", "rw");
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        valueFile.writeDouble(randomizer.nextDouble()*200);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< iterations; i++) {
        double total = 0;
        valueFile.seek(0);
        // Presumably you'd read the contents here?
    }
}
```

... except you should *also* close the file when you're done with it, using a try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7, or just a try/finally block otherwise.

Comment: @DaoWen: I've reread it - and I was answering the *second* error reported, not the first. Will edit to include both.

Comment: Your answer for the second error question is still way off. The error isn't saying that the variable is _unititialized_, but rather that the symbol _doesn't exist_. This is because he declares the variable inside the `try` block in the second example, which means it's no longer in scope for `valueFile.seek(0)`.

Comment: @DaoWen: I think you should re-read the question :) "I also get "variable valueFile might not have been initialized". I was explicitly talking about the *first version of the code*, where the variable is still in scope, but might not have a value.

Comment: You're right, I skimmed right over the top of the parenthetical with the secondary error, so when you said "second error" I thought you meant the error reported for the second example. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

```
RandomAccessFile valueFile;
```

needs to be:

```
RandomAccessFile valueFile = null;
```

> (I also get "variable valueFile might not have been initialized".)

To fix the above.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of the try catch block and then load from within it.

```
RandomAccessFile valueFile;

try
{
    valueFile = new RandomAccessFile("valuefile.txt", "rw");
    for (int i=0; i<numOfNums; i++)
        valueFile.writeDouble(randomizer.nextDouble()*200);
}
```

Comment: Don't know`who down voted you, but I've got to say, I do not recommend this approach. This is just stop the compiler nagging you, as opposed to writing good code, so it won't.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've always thought this was a correct approach, and better for readability. In a function involving io you would almost always exit upon error asap. I always separated things which did not require a try statement from those items that did for readabilities sake. With the function above it seemed that there would be processing on items after the read. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson -- There's no other way to do it, if you want the RAF created in the try block and want to access it outside.

Comment: Yes there is. Depends on what exceptions you are trying to catch when. For instance in this answer, both no write access, and disk full would both be trapped. If I wanted to handle both exceptions. I'd have one block to open the file, and one to write to it. If they were handled then my function to do both would pass back a null, not rely on something not being assigned ages ago. Might be stylistic, might be because I didn't cut my teeth on Java, but I'd go well out of my way to avoid the above.